# Approximating a holomorphic function on a relatively compact set

Tags: complex-analysis

A couple of months ago, I [asked][1] a question regarding Runge's theorem and approximating holomorphic functions. I took a break and am now trying to work on this somewhat related problem:

For me, this question makes me immediately jump to trying to apply Runge's theorem

Comment: ??? I don't see why this is not just an immediate application of Runge's theorem. Can you _state_ that theorem?

Comment: I've edited the problem statement to include Runge's theorem. I think it might be that condition $2$ using $G=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,3\}$ and $\overline{K}$ as the compact, then the problem follows. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I imagine you could get the result from that, but you'll need to be a little careful, since there's no reason (2) should be true. It's immediate from the _actual_ Runge's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Runge's theorem you cite may work with a little care; the problem is you don't have information about the components of the complement of $K$; you'd need some argument about filling in holes or something. On a second reading, the version I gave you a link to has the same difficulty,  as far as applying to this problem goes. Here's the version of the theorem that makes the problem trivial. It's in every complex book I know.

Say $\Bbb C_\infty$ is $\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$. Note that if $\lim_{z\to\infty}r(z)=\infty$ then $r$ is said to have a pole at infinity; in particular a polynomial has a pole at infinity (and not that we need it here but if $r$ is a rational function with no pole except at infinity then $r$ is a polynomial).

**Theorem** Suppose $V\subset\Bbb C$ is open. Suppose $A\subset\Bbb C_\infty$ intersects every component of $\Bbb C_\infty\setminus V$. If $f\in H(V)$ then there exists a sequence of rational functions $r_n$, each of which has no poles except at points of $A$, such that $r_n\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $V$.

Comment: So I see how that version immediately solves the problem, thank you. What do you mean, however, as an "argument about filling in holes"? A quick google gives me a reference to Remmart's book.

Comment: Well, there's no reason $K$ should satisfy (2) in your version of Runge. You could let $K'$ be $K$ plus the compact components of the complement...